# Late 80's game, post apocalyptic dinosaurs and guns

Tags: identify-this-game

I am trying to remember what was either a board game or a strategy game from the late 1980s. The setting was a post-apocalyptic USA with a campy 1950s vibe. You controlled dinosaurs that you have to upgrade to battle others. Upgrades included armor and weapons. I also remember some of the upgrade cards were labeled 'Factoids' and were shaped like CRT Televisions.

I don't think it was:

- [Lost Valley of the Dinosaurs](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/3149/lost-valley-dinosaurs)
- [Impact: The Battle for Wolf Ridge](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/23914/impact-battle-wolf-ridge)
- [Cadiliacs and Dinosaurs](https://videogamegeek.com/videogame/82408/cadillacs-and-dinosaurs) (a video game)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could it have been [Gammarauders](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1408/gammarauders)?  That has *Factoid* cards with images of TVs (with feet!) and came out in 1987.  Some, although not all, of the creatures in the game were dinosaurs.